# Set plugin’s version on the command line in Maven 2

Tags: maven-2, snapshot

I generate default quickstart Maven example, and type `mvn checkstyle:checkstyle`, it always try to use the lastest `SNAPSHOT` version. Probably it is wrong in my Nexus server, but how can I set plugin's version on the command line in Maven 2, like `2.5` for checkstyle instead of `2.6-SNAPSHOT`?

```
C:\HelloWorld>mvn checkstyle:checkstyle
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'checkstyle'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).

Project ID: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin

Reason: Error getting POM for 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin' from  the repository: Failed to resolve artifact, possibly due to a repository list that is not appropriately equipped for this artifact's metadata.
  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:pom:2.6-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  nexus (http://localhost:9081/nexus/content/groups/public)

for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin
```

I guess it could be `mvn checkstyle:2.5:checkstyle`, unfortunately it is not.

Surely if I set build dependance in `pom.xml`, it will work, but I want to see how command line can work.

Comment: If I type in complete artifact, it works
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.5:checkstyle

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you don't want to run the latest version of a plugin installed in your local repository, you need to set the version number. And for that, you need to specify a fully-qualified goal in the form of:

```
mvn groupID:artifactID:version:goal
```

So in your case:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.5:checkstyle
```

Comment: "_run the latest version of a plugin installed in your local repository_" seems not to be true. I have `maven-dependency-plugin` `2.8`, `2.10` and `3.0.0` in my local repo and Maven runs `2.8` by default. Even if I delete `2.8` Maven re-downloads it at the next run.

Answer (score 3):

My experience with a newer version of maven(3.3.9) is slightly different. If I'm not running maven in offline mode, it will ALWAYS go for a remote repo regardless of what I have in the local one.
And if it finds a newer version(based on maven-metadata.xml), it will download and use that one. What's more, it will scan multiple repos simultaneously:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin version for com.phoenixnap.oss:springmvc-raml-plugin
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.phoenixnap.oss:springmvc-raml-plugin/maven-metadata.xml in local (/home/yuranos/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repo.spring.io/milestone
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repo.spring.io/snapshot
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.spring.io/milestone
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.spring.io/snapshot
Downloading: https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/com/phoenixnap/oss/springmvc-raml-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/com/phoenixnap/oss/springmvc-raml-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/phoenixnap/oss/springmvc-raml-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/phoenixnap/oss/springmvc-raml-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /home/yuranos/.m2/repository/com/phoenixnap/oss/springmvc-raml-plugin/resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /home/yuranos/.m2/repository/com/phoenixnap/oss/springmvc-raml-plugin/resolver-status.properties
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/phoenixnap/oss/springmvc-raml-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 1.0 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /home/yuranos/.m2/repository/com/phoenixnap/oss/springmvc-raml-plugin/resolver-status.properties
Downloaded: https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/com/phoenixnap/oss/springmvc-raml-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 0.9 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /home/yuranos/.m2/repository/com/phoenixnap/oss/springmvc-raml-plugin/resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.phoenixnap.oss:springmvc-raml-plugin/maven-metadata.xml in spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.phoenixnap.oss:springmvc-raml-plugin/maven-metadata.xml in spring-milestones-libs (https://repo.spring.io/milestone)
```

What's more, maven seems to know how to compare several metadata files and select the very latest version of the artifact.
Maven makes use of Aether to resolve dependencies, based on what I see in `resolver-status.properties`:

```
    #NOTE: This is an Aether internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Mon Feb 19 23:41:24 EET 2018
maven-metadata-spring-milestones.xml.lastUpdated=1519076484366
maven-metadata-spring-snapshots.xml.error=
maven-metadata-central.xml.lastUpdated=1519076484205
maven-metadata-spring-snapshots.xml.lastUpdated=1519076484107
maven-metadata-spring-milestones-libs.xml.lastUpdated=1519076484105
maven-metadata-spring-milestones-libs.xml.error=
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1:site
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for your answer. The best answers add a little explanation to the code or command. You could [edit] this answer to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

> mvn {your groupId}:{your artifactId}:{your version}:{your goal}