# How does Maven decide what version of a plugin to use, when you don't specify any?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-central, maven-metadata

I recognized that Maven not always uses the latest version of a plugin.

For example `org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin` version 2.7 has beed released on 19th of October but on 23th of October, 2.6 was still used by Maven (`mvn sonar:sonar`).

I even remember some plugins, where the latest version was several minor releases above the version that Maven decided to use.

Is there any (central) index/list/database where Maven looks up what version to use? If yes, where can it be accessed manually?

Comment: Best is to pin all versions of used plugins in a company/corporate pom.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct, but we can't change this for all projects at once, so I want to track changes in Maven plugin's default versions.

Comment: There is no plugin default version....?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Maven resolve plugin versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128372/how-does-maven-resolve-plugin-versions)

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an ancient thread but in the interest of posterity and accuracy: all `pom.xml`s logically inherit from the [super POM](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html).  You can always see what your "real" `pom.xml` looks like by typing:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

The resulting `pom.xml` that is printed is a combination of the super POM, your `pom.xml`, and of course any parent POMs in the mix as well.

The super POM is provided by the `org.apache.maven.model.superpom.DefaultSuperPomProvider` class (https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/bce33aa2662a51d18cb00347cf2fb174dc195fb1/maven-model-builder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/model/superpom/DefaultSuperPomProvider.java#L56-L85).  The resource it loads is `org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml` (https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/bce33aa2662a51d18cb00347cf2fb174dc195fb1/maven-model-builder/src/main/resources/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml#L23-L149).

Comment: That's pretty nice to know, but the super POM does not contain any of the (default lifecycle) plugins versions.

Comment: At least as of Maven 2, it does: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Super_POM; scroll down past the first XML hairball to the second one.  Your point about it being missing from the Maven 3 super POM is a good one, however; I'll see if I can track it down.

Comment: That's pretty interesting. If this documentation would be for Maven 3.X, it would definitely answer my question. There has to be such a thing for Maven 3...

Comment: Yes, and I see that I have been lulled into complacency assuming that the 2.x super POM carried over.  Clearly it does not.

Comment: The Maven 3 super POM is provided by the `org.apache.maven.model.superpom.DefaultSuperPomProvider` class (https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/bce33aa2662a51d18cb00347cf2fb174dc195fb1/maven-model-builder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/model/superpom/DefaultSuperPomProvider.java#L56-L85).  The resource it loads can be found here: https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/bce33aa2662a51d18cb00347cf2fb174dc195fb1/maven-model-builder/src/main/resources/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml#L23-L149

Answer (score 6):

As far as i know, this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-AutomaticPluginVersionResolution) will answer your question.

> **Automatic Plugin Version Resolution**
>
> When a plugin was invoked without an explicit version given in the POM
>   or on the command line, Maven 2.x used to pick the latest version
>   available where the latest version could either be a release or a
>   snapshot. For the sake of stability, Maven 3.x prefers the latest
>   release version over the latest snapshot version.
>
> Given the threat of non-reproducible builds imposed by automatic
>   plugin version resolution, this feature is scheduled for removal as
>   far as plugin declarations in the POM are concerned. Users of Maven
>   3.x will find it output a warning when missing plugin versions are detected to encourage the addition of plugin versions to the POM or
>   one of its parent POMs. The Enforcer rule requirePluginVersions can be
>   used additionally check for missing plugin versions in the POM

Comment: I wished this would answer my question.

For example, when I do a mvn compile now using Maven 3.3.9, it takes maven-compiler-plugin 2.3.2 but 3.6.1 is the latest release (11 releases later).

Answer (score 1):

For command line execution if a version is not specified Maven looks up the latest version from the GA (group ID/artifact ID) maven-metadata.xml file.

Example:  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/maven-metadata.xml

If you're encoding command line execution of Maven goals into your builds you should specify a version for these, otherwise your builds may change as new versions of plugins are released.

Comment: This can't always be the latest.

For examble a mvn clean call uses maven-clean-plugin 2.5 but 2.6 2.6.1 and 3.0.0 are already released.