# How is default Maven plugin version decided?

Tags: java, maven

I wonder when I did not specify a plugin version in some module's `pom.xml` like in:

```
<build>
...
<plugin>
   <groudId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.0</version>
</plugin>
...
</build>
```

What is the default plugin version used when I run "mvn compile"?

I have tried it and see actually it is using `maven-compiler-plugin` version 3.1 with above plugin element commented, my Maven version is 3.6.3.

I have spent 1 hour to google through Maven's documentation and related posts, but not find exact answer. I really like to know how that version is being decided?

Comment: I wonder when I did not specify a plugin version in some module's pom.xml like in: Do you mean like this?? `<plugin>
   <groudId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>`

Comment: yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Maven resolve plugin versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128372/how-does-maven-resolve-plugin-versions)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The magic is not happening in the super pom, but in the so called `bindings descriptor` as available at https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/default-bindings.xml. 
However, they are moving to the matching packaging plugin, for example for the maven-jar-plugin it is located at https://github.com/apache/maven-jar-plugin/blob/master/src/main/filtered-resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml
These versions haven't been updated, because it would be weird if 2 users with different Maven versions have different results (e.g.  one has a broken build, the other not). Hence it is better to specify the plugin versions in the pom, don't rely of the defaults provided by Maven.

In the end it is all described at https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: Thank you, your answers exactly answered my question. From the reference you gave at the end of your post, I would gave two more related for clarification which is found from https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html.

1. https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.3/maven-core/lifecycles.html
2. https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.3/maven-core/default-bindings.html

Comment: Thanks for this, however the https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/default-bindings.xml link you provide here (and which is also provided at the bottom of https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) is now broken.

Answer (score 1):

> It is impossible for maven to work without defining versions of the
>   artifacts , so somewhere it must be mentioned, lets dig in part by
>   part.

All `pom.xml`s are  logically inherit from the [super POM](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html). You can always see what your "real" `pom.xml` looks like by typing:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

The resulting `pom.xml` that is printed is a combination of the **super POM**, your **pom.xml**, and *any parent POMs* in the mix as well.

Note from Maven 3 the **super POM** does not contain any of the (default lifecycle) plugins versions but earlier till **Maven 2** it used to have.

The Maven 3 super POM is provided by the `org.apache.maven.model.superpom.DefaultSuperPomProvider` class https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/bce33aa2662a51d18cb00347cf2fb174dc195fb1/maven-model-builder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/model/superpom/DefaultSuperPomProvider.java#L56-L85

The resource it loads can be found here: https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/bce33aa2662a51d18cb00347cf2fb174dc195fb1/maven-model-builder/src/main/resources/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml#L23-L149

---

**Edit:**

As per [Maven Coordinates](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html)

> `groupId`:`artifactId`:`version` are all required fields (although,
>   groupId and version need not be explicitly defined if they are
>   inherited from a parent - more on inheritance later). The three fields
>   act much like an address and timestamp in one. This marks a specific
>   place in a repository, acting like a coordinate system for Maven
>   projects:

**version**: This is the last piece of the naming puzzle. `groupId`:`artifactId` denotes a single project but they cannot delineate which incarnation of that project we are talking about. Do we want the junit:junit of 2018 (version 4.12), or of 2007 (version 3.8.2)? In short: code changes, those changes should be versioned, and this element keeps those versions in line. It is also used within an artifact's repository to separate versions from each other. my-project version 1.0 files live in the directory structure `$M2_REPO/org/codehaus/mojo/my-project/1.0.`

Comment: The super POM, I also looked before, but that does not say what is the version of maven-compiler-plugin. Still thankful for the information provided.

Comment: @IcyBrk , I am trying on my laptop and i feel that it is impossible to work without `version` , thedependency management is required and version must be specified either in `effective-pom` or `dependency tree.` ,  While in dependency management you can specify to use the latest version, but without Dependency management i feel it wont work. **correct me !**

Comment: have you tried to remove that dependency in the dependencyManagement and see what happend.

Comment: I removed the version from `dependencyManagement ` and it does not work, in fact I am getting **ProjectBuildingException**

Comment: No, I mean remove the dependency element for maven-compiler-plugin in dependencyManagement.