# Facing some problem while defining maven.compiler in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

**A)Summarize the problem**

There are three methods to define compiler version in pom maven.
I did not mention maven.compiler release , plugin and version it works (means maven build success)then how it is picking the compiler version and i did not mention version

**For The things ihave tried please refer section b**

1)

```
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
```

2. 

```
            <plugin> 
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>3.8.1</version> 
            <configuration> 
                <source>1.8</source> 
                <target>1.8</target> 
                <verbose>true</verbose> 
            </configuration> 
    </plugin>
```

3. 

```
<maven.compiler.release> 8</maven.compiler.release>
```

**B) What i have tried**

I remove both maven.compiler release and plugin it works then how it is picking the compiler version

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.flowing.retail</groupId>
    <artifactId>flowing-retail-kafka-shipping</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

        <spring.boot.version>2.2.5.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <spring-cloud-stream.version>Horsham.RELEASE</spring-cloud-stream.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-stream.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- required to add JSR310 time formats for Jackson to ObjectMapper -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>              
                <configuration>                         
                      <mainClass>io.flowing.retail.shipping.ShippingApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
             </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

2. I define invalid maven.compiler.release. It then also works

   4.0.0
   io.flowing.retail
   flowing-retail-kafka-shipping
   0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

   <maven.compiler.release>108</maven.compiler.release>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

   ```
            <spring.boot.version>2.2.5.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
            <spring-cloud-stream.version>Horsham.RELEASE</spring-cloud-stream.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-cloud-stream.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <!-- required to add JSR310 time formats for Jackson to ObjectMapper -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                 <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>              
                    <configuration>                         
                          <mainClass>io.flowing.retail.shipping.ShippingApplication</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                 </plugin>
                 <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                          <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                          </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
   ```

Comment: If you use spring boot, set `<java.version>` and nothing else.

Comment: The compiler argument `-release` was introduced in Java 9. Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65965917/edit) your question and explain what the problem is? Are you wondering which parameter overrides the other ones?

Comment: @dan1st ,There are three methods to define compiler version in pom maven. I did not mention maven.compiler release , plugin and version it works (means maven build success)then how it is picking the compiler version and i did not mention version

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz can u please refer section B of this question i have done some edits , if u kow please answer it will be helpful

Comment: Just set a property `java.version` and spring boot will manage source/target/release.

Comment: @IshanGarg: I edited my answer to address what I understand _"picking the compiler version"_. I hope you meant the same thing. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Let me first clarify the expression *"picking the compiler version"* you use in your question. The compiler you use is configured through the `compilerId` and `compilerVersion` options and it's usually the compiler of the JDK you installed. We are talking about setting the compatibility options of your compiler.]

The properties you mention are used to provide the `-source`, `-target` and `--release` arguments to the `javac` compiler (or equivalent if you use another compiler).

Since `--release` was introduced in Java 9, which one applies depends on the JDK used to run maven. If you provide the `--release` argument:

- on JDK 9 and higher, maven will ignore the `-source` and `-target` parameters,
- on JDK 8 and lower, the compilation will fail miserably.

The **maven-compiler-plugin** specifies three ways to provide these parameters:

1. in the `<configuration>` section of a `<plugin>` tag. This one overrides the others,
2. as a property in your `pom.xml`. This one applies if you didn't specify the parameter in a `<configuration>` section,
3. if you didn't specify any of the above, a default for `-source` and `-target` applies (`--release` does not have a default).

You can find the defaults in the `maven-compiler-plugin.jar` (resource `META-INF/maven/plugin.xml`):

```xml
<configuration>
    ...
    <release implementation="java.lang.String">${maven.compiler.release}</release>
    ...
    <source implementation="java.lang.String" default-value="1.6">${maven.compiler.source}</source>
    ...
    <target implementation="java.lang.String" default-value="1.6">${maven.compiler.target}</target>
</configuration>
```

So, since you are using version `3.8.1` of the plugin, if you don't specify anything at all, Java 6 applies.

**TL;DR**: if you use Java 9 and higher, your configuration options will apply in the order 3., 2., 1.

**Edit**: If your compiler supports it, between setting the `-source/-target` and `--release` options, I would always choose the latter. With the `--release` option, you won't have issues like [this one](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-java/issues/516). What happened there is: the source syntax was compatible with Java 8 (`-source 1.8`), the classes could be read by a JVM 8 (`-target 1.8`), but a method changed signature (in a backward, but not forward compatible way) between Java 8 and 11 and the library would not work with JRE 8.

Comment: i just want to confirm one more thing like if i use release should i use maven-compiler-plugin or not

Comment: Yes, you should specify that you want version 3.8.1 of the plugin. Otherwise you'll get a very old version of the plugin (as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59557884/11748454)), which silently ignores the `maven.compiler.version` property. I believe that plugin version `3.6.0` was the first one to support this configuration property.