# How to find a Maven dependency version declaration imported from a BOM

Tags: maven, maven-bom

A multi-module parent POM declares the following BOM import:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.io.platform.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then a module POM declares a Hibernate dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

How do I find out with Maven command line or IntelliJ where the effective Hibernate version is defined?

Running `mvn dependency:tree` against my module yields:

```
...
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
...
```

which is not exactly helpful because it looks no different than if I managed the Hibernate version myself. If you have to do this manually you

- start at `platform-bom-2.0.3.RELEASE.pom`, search for Hibernate -> nothing
- go to its parent `spring-boot-starter-parent-1.3.3.RELEASE.pom`, search for Hibernate -> nothing
- go to *its* parent `spring-boot-dependencies-1.3.3.RELEASE.pom`, search for Hibernate -> finally...

But what an ordeal. Of course you could check http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions but isn't that information Maven should be able to find on its own?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I was trying to use `mvn help:effective-pom -Dverbose` from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58142268/525036), but it didn't work for me because it was using maven-help-plugin:2.2, and [`-Dverbose` was introduced in 3.2.0](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html#verbose).

Instead, you should thus [force the version in the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2871054/525036):

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:effective-pom -Dverbose=true -Doutput=effective-pom.xml
```

(better to use `-Doutput` because the file can be big and it is not convenient to read it in a terminal)

Comment: If the dependency comes from a bom it nicely reports that. But if the bom also comes from another bom then this is not shown.

Comment: @thehpi and this is just insane, how easy this is with gradle (imo) and how _impossible_ it is with maven.

Comment: I hit the same issue @thehpi describes. I did not find any other way but to manually inspect the content of all BOMs.

Answer (score 48):

`mvn help:effective-pom -Dverbose=true` gives the information of location of pom from where an entry comes in effective pom in comment.
reference: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse, when viewing the pom in XML format (i.e in the "pom.xml" tab, not the "Overview" tab), simply put the mouse cursor over the artifact name and a popup will appear with the effective version and the location where it is defined.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to [How do I show the Maven POM hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120294/how-do-i-show-the-maven-pom-hierarchy) it looks like it not possible with a simple command.

You should write your own plugin or script to climb the hierarchy to the top and find the artifact you are interested in.

*Small Tip*: to retrieve the version of an artifact you're using, you can open the pom.xml in the Idea Editor and hold *Ctrl* while *hovering on* the artifactId, and the full name of its pom will be displayed, with its version.

Comment: which is why I _hate_ maven. There are other things that trigger me quite a lot, too.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things. First the output of dependency:tree prints out what the final result is. The question here is why you don't believe it? And why do you manage the version yourself if you are using a BOM...

Apart from that you could use:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

And if you search a little bit better than you will come to the [following pom file](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-1.3.3.RELEASE.pom) which contains the version definition like this:

```xml
<hazelcast.version>3.5.5</hazelcast.version>
<hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
<hibernate-validator.version>5.2.4.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
<hikaricp.version>2.4.3</hikaricp.version>
<hikaricp-java6.version>2.3.13</hikaricp-java6.version>
<hornetq.version>2.4.7.Final</hornetq.version>
```

which are exactly the version which is printed out already by dependency:tree.

Comment: Thanks, but all of that is in my Q already. I never said I didn't believe what `dependency:tree` printed and I never said I managed the version myself. The Q is "where the effective Hibernate version is defined". Also, I did list the POM you also mentioned. The point is, what you state as "search a little bit better" is IMO an ordeal. I was expecting Maven to be able to tell me right away where the version is defined (i.e. in which POM).

Comment: Sounds like a good idea for maven-dependency-plugin or any other plugin which can solve such problem...

Comment: mvn help:effective-pom -Dverbose=true gives the information of location of pom from where an entry comes in effective pom.

Answer (score -1):

My answer would be really similar to @Didier L. I was getting error due to the .xml file extension `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:effective-pom -Dverbose=true -Doutput=effective-pom`