# How to determine where a bom has been depended(imported) in maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a project with lots of dependencies. There is a conflicting dependency in my pom, IDEA shows the dependency was imported from a bom that I did't use. I want to exclude it, but I can't find where the bom(not the jar) has been imported.
I have tried `dependency:tree`,  it does not show boms, only jars.
Is there any way to show where boms have been imported?

Comment: If the BOM is not in your POM, it is either defined in the parent POM (or their parent...) or it is part of another BOM. I would start by searching the parent POM hierarchy.

Comment: Check your parent hierarchy or `<dependency-management>` tag in your POM. The BOM should be coming from there.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I have tried this, but the hierarchy is so complex, may take a lot of time to figure it out in this way... So I wonder if there is a simple way...

Answer (score 2):

`mvn help:effective-pom -Dverbose` will annotate all dependencies with their sources.

Comment: That is a great tip. Really useful!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723097/how-to-find-a-maven-dependency-version-declaration-imported-from-a-bom#comment117921500_58647530